# Teradata SQL format a decimal field

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a decimal field (19,4) in teradata and I need it in a specific format:

- group separator as the point
- decimal character as the comma
- only two decimal digits
- integer part of the number must be grouped 3 by 3

I have already tried FORMAT, TO_CHAR and CAST functions. I have also tried NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter in those functions. I think I am missing some rationale in TERADATA SQL, I'll appreciate some help.

The idea is very simple:

```
SELECT some_decimal_field_in_proper_format_described_above
FROM some_table
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CAST/FORMAT the group separator and decimal separator are determined by the SDF "locale" for your system. But if you want something different you can use TO_CHAR with D for the decimal and G for the group separator in the format string and custom values for NUMERIC_CHARACTERS:

```
TO_CHAR(x,'S999G999G999G999G990D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
```

Comment: Just one more question: do you know if  this solution is a big issue for the query performance?

Comment: Not a big issue. For a large answer set, might see a slight increase in CPU consumption.